# DB2 Function Not Found When Calling from PHP

Tags: php, db2

I am attempting to call a DB2 function from PHP using zend_db to connect to DB2, and calling a SQL statement like so:

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC, mylib.testfunc(colA, colB, colC)
FROM otherlib.tableABC
WHERE colA = ... etc
```

(Just for reference, this is to call an RPG program that returns a specific value, so it is only returning one value). This works in an ACS Run SQL Scripts window, but when I try on Zend, I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Db2_Exception' with message 'TESTFUNC in MYLIB type *N not found. SQLCODE=-204'
```

I have double-checked to make sure my function does actually exist and it's in mylib. Doing a google search came up with nothing really helpful. Why would it be telling me that it doesn't exist? Is there something specific I have to configure when connecting to DB2 through Zend_DB?

In case it's important, I made the function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mylib.testfunc(iA DECIMAL(2,0), iB CHAR(4), iC DECIMAL(2,0))
RETURNS CHAR(10)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE oReturn CHAR(10) DEFAULT ' ';
    -- Here I call a procedure I created to call the RPG
    -- and format data...
    RETURN oReturn;
END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the userid (account-name) for connecting to Db2 the same between PHP and 'ACS Run SQL Scripts' ?  If not, verify that the account used for PHP has execute access to the function *and* whatever stored-procedures or external programs that function invokes.   Additionally, when your SQL function CALLs the stored-procedure does it use a qualified name (with a schema)  or not, and additionally is that stored-procedure catalogued?

Comment: Why is it always a permissions error? Thank you! I didn't even think to check that, usually the errors tell me that "xyz does not have permission to object abc" or what have you. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the userid (account-name) for connecting to Db2 the same between PHP and 'ACS Run SQL Scripts' ?

If not, verify that the account used for PHP has execute access to the function and whatever stored-procedures or external programs/routines the function invokes.

Additionally, when your SQL function CALLs the stored-procedure consider using a qualified stored-procedure name.